# Angular Material Datepicker toggle icon click event

Tags: javascript, angular, datepicker, angular-material

Is it possible to somehow catch click event on angular material datepicker toggle icon? I want trigger function foo().

My implementation looks like:

```
          <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
            <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Date">
            <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker" (click)="foo()"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
            <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
          </mat-form-field>
```

I have already tried put (click)="foo()" to mat-datepicker-toggle and mat-datepicker element but event not triggered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use opened and closed event emitter provided by angular date picker component to listen open and close of calander component.

```
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
            <input  matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Date">
            <mat-datepicker-toggle            
             matSuffix [for]="picker" (click)="foo()"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
            <mat-datepicker 
            #ref
            (opened)="toggle(ref)"
            (closed)="toggle(ref)"
            #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uvxcn5)

Comment: you save my day

Answer (score 0):

Try to (focus)="foo()" instead of (click)="foo()"